# consulta de SQL Server no devuelve registros en la ejecucion dentro de un php

Tags: php, sql-server-2017

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una consulta en relacion a un dato que se esta registrando,es decir que se desea ver la informacion despues del insert; la consulta que estoy ejecutando es la siguiente:

```
$rows = count($array_pp);
    //echo $array_pp[0].'-'.$rows;
    include_once("BD.php");
    if($rows == 0){
        $muestra = '';
    }else{
        $muestra = '<table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>PPBU</th>
                            <th>MANUFACTURE ORDER</th>
                            <th>JOB NUMBER</th>
                            <th>TASK NAME</th>
                            <th>QUANTITY</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>   
                        <tbody>';

        for($k = 0 ; $k < $rows; $k++){
                $ppbu = $array_pp[$k];
                //echo $ppbu.'-'.$rows.'-'.$k.'</br>';

                //---procedemos con la consulta sql
                $sql = "select  ppbu, ManufactureNumber, JobNumber, taskname, quantity
                                from 
                            (SELECT ppbu, ManufactureNumber, JobNumber, taskname, quantity,
                                case when Quantity<>0
                                    then row_number() over(partition by ManufactureNumber order by manufacturenumber, [sequence])
                                    else 0
                                end as numCuenta
                            
                                FROM [DB].[db1].[lpmBultos]
                                where ppbu  in ('$ppbu')
                                ) abcdefg
                                order by numcuenta desc ";
                
                $query = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sql);
                
                while ($fila  = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){
                        $muestra .= '<tr>
                                        <td>'.$fila['bulto'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$fila['ManufactureNo'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$fila['JobNumber'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$fila['tarea'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$fila['cantidad'].'</td>
                                    </tr> ';
                        echo $fila['ManufactureNumber'];            
                }//--fin del while
                
                echo $sql;       

        }//--fin del for
        unset($array_pp);    
        $muestra .= '</tbody></table>';
    }
    return $muestra;
```

El array_pp, viene con dos valores los cuales consulto pero he identificado que el error se encuentra en el momento de ejecutar el query: $query = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sql);
ya que cuando comento esta instruccion y lo mando a imprimir en pantalla efectivamente se me imprime 2 veces, por cada uno de los datos del array.

Podrian ayudarme a identificar mi error, infinitas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: el archivo de la conexion funciona, correctamente, al hacer ctrl+clik sobre la variable $conexion me dirige al archivo incluido, confirma que me permite conectarme

Comment: Otro comentario es que la consulta SQL me devuelve un sólo registro ya que utilizo top 1

Comment: ¿Por qué rodeas la variable por comillas simples aquí: `where ppbu  in ('$ppbu')`? Lo que `IN()` espera es una lista de valores separados por coma. La instrucción debe ir así: `where ppbu  in ($ppbu)`, si `$ppbu` tiene valores que son cadenas, debes cuidar al producir los datos que vengan con sus comillas, por ejemplo: `$ppbu='cadena1','cadena2';`. Aunque lo mejor sería que uses **consultas preparadas**. Depura tu consulta con un `var_dump($query);`. Es muy probable que sea `false` o que no encuentre filas por lo que te acabo de comentar.

Comment: De todos modos, hay más cosas a mejorar en tu código. No conviene hacer consultas en bucle. Haz una sola consulta, y luego muestra los datos. Si el bucle tiene 1000 iteracciones vas a hacer 1000 consultas, hastiando al SGBD. Otro problema es tu estilo de programación que yo llamo *optimista* (programar ignorando los errores, no verificando nada). Debes verificar todo lo verificable. Por ejemplo, pasas a leer filas, sin saber si hay filas (programación *optimista*). La consulta pudo haber fallado, o pudo no traer filas, debes verificar eso (programación *pesimista*).

Comment: Hola, estoy completamente deacruerdo contigo @A.Cedano, debo cambiar mi metodo de programacion, es una falta grave que debo superar. En relacion a lo que comentas,nose si sera valido pero cuando comentaba la linea $query = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sql); y hacia un echo $query; me mostraba las dos consultas; y las copiaba y pegaba en SqlSqerver y me funcionaban, voy a revisar esta situacion probablemente estoy dejando pasar por alto algo de lo que me comentas, agradezco infinitamente tus observaciones, solo asi podemos ser mejores, gracias por tu ayuda y tiempo.....seguiremos preguntando...

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que hay en `$array_pp` para tener una idea sobre los datos con los que se está trabajando?